# Certain errors in uninstantiated template not reported by g++

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Consider this example:

```
class A
{
  void foo();
  public:
  void bar();
};

template <class> class B
{
  B()
  {
    A a;
    a.foo();    // 1
    A::bar();   // 2
    a.bar(1);   // 3
  }
};
```

Note `B` is never instantiated.

`clang++` reports all three marked lines as erroneous. `g++` (4.8.3) accepts lines `1` and `2` and only reports line `3`.

If `B` is instantiated, `g++` happily reports all three lines as erroneous.

Is this a `g++` bug? One would think so. `A` is not a dependent name and its members should be checked normally at template definition time. Are there nuances I don't see?

Comment: 1 can be made valid for a specialization with a `friend` declaration, and 2 can be made valid for a specialization by deriving from `A`, whereas 3 can never be made valid for a specialization.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker `A` is not a template, all of its friends (none) are already known. `B` of course could have a specialization that derives from `A`, but this `B::B` would not be a member of that specialization.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as [hvd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24934224/822669). ie. it's more difficult to check that 1 and 2 are invalid than it is to check that 3 is invalid, and since errors are not required, minimal effort is acceptable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those pre-instantiation messages aren't enforced by the standard and are up to the compiler

n3337 § 14.6 - 8

> No diagnostic shall be issued for a template definition for which a
>   valid specialization can be generated. If no valid specialization can
>   be generated for a template definition, and that template is not
>   instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, **no diagnostic
>   required.**

emphasis mine

Comment: I have never thought that the quoted passage refers to such errors. But after re-reading the relevant pages in the standard I see that you are right. Even things like `int* i = 23.45;` can be left undiagnosed.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible in general to tell whether `a.foo();` or `A::bar();` are an error at template definition time, even for those specific definitions of `A::foo` and `A::bar`.

Generally speaking, `a.foo();` could be valid if `A` had some specialisations of `B<T>` as a friend, but not others, which would make the validity dependent on the template argument.

Generally speaking, `A::bar();` could be valid if `B<T>` had `A` as a base class, directly or indirectly, and template classes do not generally know their base class yet at template definition time.

Even though it's possible to detect that neither of these is possible *here* (`A` has no friends, and `B<T>` has no base), it requires significant effort for little benefit. Because of this, it makes sense to simply always perform such checks at instantiation time, and that's the approach GCC has taken.

There is actually no rule in C++ that *requires* this to be diagnosed at template definition time (as Marco A.'s answer rightly points out). It's only when a template is instantiated that any errors in the template definition render the program ill-formed with a requirement for a diagnostic, per 2.2p1 bullet point 8:

> The program is ill-formed if any instantiation fails.

In your program, there is no instantiation, so there is no instantiation that fails.

Comment: Never mind, I should have read more fully; I stopped after the two "could be valid", since it could not here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah, thanks for the clarification. Hopefully this edit prevents others from reading it the same way you did.