# VS 2013 templates dont compile

Tags: c++, templates

I recently switched from CB to VS(lack of std::thread support)
But now i have next problem dunno how to fix it maybe someone have it before.

Here it is

```
bool addTask(std::string contextName, std::string taskName)
{
    sdasdsadsaddssd
    return false;
}
```

Yup we have error.

```
template<typename... Args> bool addTask(std::string contextName, std::string taskName, Args... args)
{
    fdfgfdfgfggf
    return false;
}
```

And now we dont

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Question is: Why templates mask errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions are not functions. They are *templates*.

Templates are instantiated on-demand. That means, until you ask for a function to be created from your function template, there is no function. No function, no error.

Although, since your example shows an honest-to-God syntax error and not a semantic error dependent on a template argument, in other compilers [it *does* still cause a failed build](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df0da173d403b357) in the first phase of compilation. [The standard doesn't require this, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934001/560648), so Visual Studio isn't misbehaving.

Comment: Depends on the compiler. IIRC VS's template engine does little more than brace matching.