# Is the body of function template required to be semantic checked when it is defined?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I've tested 4 compilers:

1. VC++14
2. Clang 3.9
3. g++ 6.0
4. Clang/C2 (VS2015 bundle)

The results differ. I list the compilers that accept the code in the comment followed.

```
struct S
{
    void mf() {}
};

template<class T>
void fun(T dependent)
{
    non_existent_var = 5; // 1, 4
    non_existent_f(5); // 1, 4
    S s;
    s.non_existent_mf(); // 1, 4
    s.mf(5); // 1, 4
    non_existent_f(dependent); // 1, 2, 3, 4
    s.non_existent_mf(dependent); // 1, 4
    s.mf(dependent); // 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

I'm a little surprised that Clang/C2 compiles differently than its official counterpart, maybe it tries to mimic MSVC...

Is the compiler required to do semantic analysis like name-lookup, overloading resolution, etc in template ?

Comment: My understanding from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/04/introducing-clang-with-microsoft-codegen-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx) is that `Clang/C2` is just using `clang` to parse the code, it still uses `VS2015` to compile it so the behaviour should be the same as VS

Comment: Related to [two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed)

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933592/certain-errors-in-uninstantiated-template-not-reported-by-g)